# How to download youtube downloader in ubuntu?

Tags: youtube-dl

I have given a command to download Youtube downloader as sudo apt-get install youtube-dl.
What to do to save this???

Comment: What do you mean “save it”? If you want to save a terminal command or any piece of text for later, use your favourite text editor.

Comment: If you're asking where to run it, press Ctrl-Alt-T, which will open a terminal. You're supposed to type/paste that command in the terminal and press enter.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install youtube-dl
```

Installs youtube-dl. To use it you need the url of a YouTube (or supported) video. There are many options available with this program, but the gist would be

```
 youtube-dl -o [name of output file] [YouTube URL]
```

A generic working example would be

```
 youtube-dl -o file.mp4 http://youtu.be/PvkMEoqmbBA
```

For more help see man page or check out the [documentation here](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#readme)